# upgrading my website to fit google chrome and firefox

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, system.net.mail

I'm programming a web site in asp.net using vb, and I need to upgrade it so all of the functions will be active for google chrome and firefox as well.

For instance I'm using System.Net.Mail for sending mails.
Sending mails when using the website with internet explorer works perfectly fine, but in chrome and firefox the mails are not sent (the to list remains empty).

I would love to get some help about this,
Thank you.

Comment: i dont have much idea of .net but...how does browser affect sending mails...i think it should be a server side thing

Answer (score 2):

Sending emails serverside has nothing to do with browsers.

There might be some reason why the button (?) that should submit the form isnt working in other browsers than IE.

You might need to check if you have some invalid javascript, or such on the button.

/M

Comment: thank you for the reply, the button is not working in chrome nor firefox. I looked at the source of some websites and noticed the source always has input as type=submit and not as buttons.
I tried to change it to type=submit, and go the OnSubmit function, instead of the OnClick function, but now I can't redirect to another page from the OnSubmit for some reason which I don't know. 
Any help with that? 

My code:

Response.Redirect("SentMessage.aspx?m=1")

I guess Response.Redirect is not working because there is no response on the OnSubmit function?

I'm cluless..

Comment: Do you have <form-tags? i.e <form method="post" action="somepage.asp">......</form>